# Save R output to a different directory

Tags: r, save, output

I am running some R code on a Windows computer using RStudio and my code generates Excel files and netCDF files periodically (dozens of them eventually). I don't want them to clutter my working directory. Is there a way to save the files to a directory called "Output" (ex:  C:/.../original file path/Output) in the parent directory? I would like a way to change my current working directory to a different directory. I understand there is getwd() and setwd() but how do I set the path to the output directory without typing out the entire windows path (for example: setwd(current source file path for windows or Mac/output). My collaborator uses a Mac and he would have his output stored there as well.

Comment: why don't you use `write.xlsx(x=df, file = "C:/.../original file path/Output/file.xlsx",
row.names = FALSE)` ?

Comment: Thanks. But what about saving non Excel output files (images, pdf, netCDF etc.) to a different location other than the parent directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `file` argument in your `write*` function. If your `Output` directory is in your working directory, it works like this:

```
write.xlsx(df, file = "Output/table.xlsx")
write.csv(df, file = "Output/table.csv")
```

Comment: You have functions for each type of file: ggsave, jpeg, ... And each one of them has a `file` argument.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify an argument in your write.csv function and other similar write functions which specifies your path.

```
#Output path
OutPath<- "C:/blah/blahblah/op/"

#Table to dump as output
OutTbl <- iris 

write.csv(OutTbl, file = OutPath)
```

Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html

Comment: Most of the output functions will have an argument for file destination. The following post gives some idea on the topic, https://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/. Another tip would be to use the help function (?function_name) to look up what arguments are allowed. Something like ?write.csv() would show the documentation of the function if there is any present which in most of the cases tells you about what arguments you can pass.